# Confusion about Notation for Twisting Sheaf and Very Ample Invertible Sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm a bit confused by some notation in Hartshorne's chapter II (theorems II.5.17, II.7.6, and some discussion on ample invertible sheaves in section 7).

> **Theorem 5.17** (Serre). Let $X$ be a projective scheme over a noetherian ring $A$, let $\mathcal{O}(1)$ be a very ample invertible sheaf on $X$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Then there is an integer $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, the sheaf $\mathcal{F}(n)$ can be generated by a finite number of global sections.
>
> *Proof.* Let $i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_A^r$ be a closed immersion of $X$ into a projective space $A$, such that $i^*(\mathcal{O}(1)) = \mathcal{O}_X(1)$... [The remainder of the paragraph is devoted to reducing to the case where $X$ is Proj of a polynomial ring.]

First, what is meant by the hypothesis "$\mathcal{O}(1)$ be a very ample invertible sheaf on $X$", since, a priori, $X$ is not projective space or Proj of a graded ring? I see that one can appeal to Corollary 5.16 to see that $X$ is $\mathrm{Proj}(S)$ for some graded ring $S$, finitely generated by $S_1$ as an $S_0 = A$-algebra. Then one can take $\mathcal{O}(1) = \widetilde{S(1)}$. Then this is very ample since we can use the description of $S$ to construct a closed immersion $i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_A^r$ with $i^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_A^r}(1)) = \mathcal{O}_X(1)$ (by Proposition 5.12(c)), which is just $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Is this the correct interpretation?

Second, on p. 153, this result is later quoted as having established: for $\mathcal{L}$ any very ample invertible sheaf on a projective scheme $X$ over $A$, for any coherent $\mathcal{F}$, there is an $n_0$ such that $n \geq n_0$ implies $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{L}^n$ is generated by global sections, which appears slightly different than the above result, since we worked with the particular very ample invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$. Based on the above argument, it seems every very ample invertible sheaf over a projective scheme (at least those coming from closed immersions coming from surjective ring maps, by proposition 5.12(c)) will be isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$. Is this true? If it's not, in what sense was the quoted result proven by theorem 5.17? Also, is this rephrasing merely meant to suggest the definition of *ample* provided on p. 153?

Finally, I am confused about the notation found in the proof of theorem 7.6, in chapter II. The setting is $X$ a scheme of finite type over a noetherian ring $A$, and $\mathcal{L}$ an invertible sheaf on $X$. One direction of the theorem is that if $\mathcal{L}^m$ is very ample implies $\mathcal{L}$ is ample. The proof begins with $i: X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}_A^n$, an immersion with $\mathcal{L}^m \simeq i^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$. Then given any coherent $\mathcal{F}$, consider the closure $\overline{X}$ in projective space and $\overline{\mathcal{F}}$ the coherent sheaf which is the extension of $\mathcal{F}$ to $\overline{X}$. Then it is noted that if $\overline{\mathcal{F}} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}(l)$ is generated by global sections, hence $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(l)$ is also. My question is, what is the meaning of $\mathcal{O}_X(l)$? The map $i$ is just an immersion, so we don't know that $X$ is Proj of some graded ring. Is $\mathcal{O}_X(l)$ just a short-hand for $\mathcal{L}^l$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ in the statement of the theorem is just a name for an invertible sheaf which by hypothesis is very ample. The motivation of such a name is exactly the fact that a very ample invertible sheaf $L$, plus a choice of a basis of $\Gamma(X, L)$, where $X$ is a variety over some algebraically closed field, is the same as giving a closed immersion $i:X\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ plus an isomorphism $\phi: L \simeq i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$. As you were suggesting, $\mathcal{O}_X(l)$ is a shorthand for $L^l$.

The isomorphism $\phi$ above shows that every very ample line bundle is isomorphic to $i^*\mathcal{O}(1)$, or $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ if you prefer this notation. Let me remark that there is not a canonically defined invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ on $X$ as in the case of $\mathbb{P}^n$. In other terms, there is not a canonically defined very ample invertible sheaf $L$ on $X$. This is the same as saying that you can embed $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ in different ways, and it can be that the associated very ample line bundles $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ are one different from each other.

For example, think of a non hyperelliptic curve of genus 3. You have different embeddings given by $K$ and $2K$, where $K$ is the canonical line bundle. By embedding the curve using these two line bundles, you have that $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ will be isomorphic to $K$ in the first case and to $2K$ in the second one. You can also see this by looking at $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ : this is isomorphic both to $Proj(k[x,y])$ and $Proj(k[u,v,w]/(uw-v^2))$ , so that the $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ in the first case is the sheafification of the $k[x,y]$-module $k[x,y](1)$ , in the other case is the sheafification of $k[x,y](2)$. Clearly, in the case of the projective line you do have a canonical $\mathcal{O}(1)$ but this is a special case, and that's because you have a canonical embedding, if you want, of the projective line into a projective space, namely the identity (you can also see this by looking at the functorial definition of the projective line). But in general, you do not have such a canonical embedding.

Comment: I'm still confused why on p. 153, theorem 5.17 is referred to as having shown for any very ample sheaf $L$ on $X$ a projective scheme over a noetherian ring $A$, $L$ is ample. I guess, more succinctly, I am asking, is every very ample sheaf on a projective scheme $X$ over a noetherian ring isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: I added an example in the end, hoping that it clarifies a little bit more.

Comment: Ah, yes, I guess I was confused on the point that $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ does not always mean the same thing, and depends on the embedding into projective space. Thank you!

Comment: @Andrea This might be a long shot since the question is six months old, but I just wanted to clarify something. In your answer you say

"The notation $\mathcal{O}_{X}(1)$ in the statement of the theorem  is just a name for an invertible sheaf..."

That would make sense, except that the notation $\mathcal{O}_{X}(1)$ is not used in the theorem's statement. He uses $\mathcal{O}(1)$ in the statement to denote a very ample sheaf on $X$. But in the proof says that $i^{*}(\mathcal{O}(1)) = \mathcal{O}_{X}(1)$. Is it a typo in the statement and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is meant to be $\mathcal{O}_{X}(1)$?

Comment: @notes might also have some input, I just couldn't tag you both in the same comment

Comment: I think I settled on: $\mathcal{O}(1)$ in the statement of the theorem is any very ample invertible sheaf on $X$, the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ in the statement $i^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$ refers to the twisting sheaf on projective space (definition on p. 120). I think it's just a typo.